# Conditional AJAX Post through PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form where I select a Name and it auto populates two other dropboxes. I have an AJAX script where it's passing a variable to another page to pull in the data from a query and display it. It works great for one dropbox however I'd like to make it update another dropbox. **Currently, it's updating both of my dropboxes with the same data.**

The script I have is:

> ```
> $(function()
> {
>   $(window).load(function()
>   {
>       $('#fullname1').change(function()
>       {
>           var parentValue = $(this).val();
>           var supervisor = "#supervisor1";
>           var shift = "#shift1";
>
>           if( parentValue.length != "" )
>           {
>               $.ajax(
>               {
>                   url: 'level.php',
>                   data: {parent: parentValue},
>                   success: function(data)
>                   {
>                       $(supervisor).html(data);  //dropbox1
>                       $(shift).html(data);       //dropbox2
>                   }
>               });
>           }
>           else
>           {
>               $('#shift1').html('<option value="">Please Select</option>');
>           }
>       });
>   });
> });
> ```

The other page it's passing to (level.php) is:

(My queries here)

> ```
> echo '<option value="'. $aValues['Shift'] .'">'. $aValues['Shift'] .'</option>';
> ```

How could I set it up so that it knows which dropbox to update? The other dropbox will look similar to the line above except it'll be $aValues['Supervisor'] instead. I'm thinking an if/else statement but not sure how to do that with AJAX involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

If you want to return 2 separate outputs, you'll want to use JSON.  This will let you return more complex data structures that can be created by PHP and read by Javascript.

*level.php*

```
$output = array(
    'supervisor' => '<option value="'. $aValues['Supervisor'] .'">'. $aValues['Supervisor'] .'</option>',
    'shift' => '<option value="'. $aValues['Shift'] .'">'. $aValues['Shift'] .'</option>',
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

*updated AJAX*

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: 'level.php',
    data: {parent: parentValue},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
        $(supervisor).html(data.supervisor);  //dropbox1
        $(shift).html(data.shift);            //dropbox2
    }
});
```

*Note:* notice the use of [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in the PHP script and the addition of `dataType: 'json'` in the `$.AJAX` call which will parse the response as a JSON string and `data` will be an object.

---

**Old Answer:**

Change:

```
parentValue.length != ""
```

To:

```
parentValue.length > 0
```

*Note:* this can also be `if(parentValue.length) {}`, because that will only evaluate to true if `parentValue.length > 0`.

Comment: Thank you. However, this doesn't change the fact that both dropboxes will be updated. I can't figure out a way to update them respectively from level.php instead of running another level2.php for the other dropbox.

Comment: @theflarenet oh I missed that, my bad. What value determines which dropbox is updated in `level.php`?

Comment: Nothing. Sorry for being pretty vague here. I'm trying to figure out a way to implement it to run two separate outputs.

Comment: @theflarenet let me know if my updated answer with JSON helps.

Comment: You have no idea how happy I am right now. Your help is greatly appreciated. It works as I intend it to... and it encourages me to read up on JSON. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, you should read up on it. It is purely meant to be created and read by programming languages, and most APIs work with JSON (sometimes XML). I always use it with my AJAX calls :)